# Magento 2 REST API create for post operation

Tags: magento2, rest-api, repository

I am a newbie in **Magento**. I am trying to create a **Magento** Rest API for post operation.I go through many online resources but none of it clarify my doubt. I am trying to create an API for an operation  which uses a table having three fields - 1.ID 2.NAME 3.CREATED AT .Now I want to populate this table using Rest API. I found resources where an interface is created at  API/DATA  and it is implemented at MODEL/DATA .I don't understand what methods should I write in it and how it works and what is the use of it.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried customer registration API for the same ?